# Make box that fits video in aspect ratio, plus static sized footer

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to have something that looks a bit like this:

[image: Basic Video Container]

Where the bear image in the middle is a video. The div which contains the video should be 16:9, and the footer should be some static height and 100% width.

Although I have found a [handy little mixin for matching an aspect ratio](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/maintain-aspect-ratio-mixin/), I am having trouble reconciling it with the statically sized bottom part.

To start with the video container, I essentially had the following:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <video src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" autoplay />
  </div>
</div>
```

With the following (S)CSS:

```
.container {
  position: relative;

  &::before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 56.25%;  // 16:9
  }

  & > .content {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
  }
}
```

How could I add this statically sized bar to the bottom of the box that maintains aspect ratio?

For convenience of answering, [here is a codepen with what I more or less have](https://codepen.io/AlexFrazer/pen/MpdVNp)

Answer (score 1):

The outer container usually has a height of 0, it's the padding that stretches around the video like saran wrap.

**SNIPPET**

```css
html {
  font: 400 16px/1.428 Consolas;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0 none transparent;
}

.vWrap {
  border: 0 none transparent;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.vid {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto%;
  max-height: 96%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class='vWrap'>
  <video id='vid1' class='vid' src='http://media6000.dropshots.com/photos/1381926/20170326/005611.mp4' controls>
  </video>
</div>
<footer class='footer'></footer>
```